# VBA error 1004 on Paste from CSV file with CSV file opened first

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner on Excel VBA and working on a little tool at work. We use a tool to measure our NPS-score, and therefore I can download all our comments as CSV file. I created a VBA, to paste all these comments in an worksheet and convert it to columns and do the math.

If I open my Excel file first, then download the comments, manually copy the comments and run the script, it works fine. But if I download the comments at first, then open my Excel file and run the script, it throws a 1004 error, Method Paste of class Worksheet failed.

I've tried a lot of answers on here, but none of them seems to work. This is the part of script in the beginning to paste the comments:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

wb.Activate

Sheets("Hulpblad").Visible = -1
Sheets("Hulpblad").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Hulpblad").Range("A1")

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I also tried to record a macro and use the Excel generated code, but all the answers give the same error.

Next to that, by some users of the script it doesn't matter in which order you open the files, it always throws the 1004 error. Can somebody please help :-)

Answer (score 0):

1004 is an error, that is generated, when you try to change a protected sheet.

In your code, you are trying to paste a value, which cannot be done, because the sheet is protected.

Try to unprotect it first, before pasting the value and then protect it again.

Comment: This particular sheet is unprotected, it's hidden, but before I paste the values, I unhide this sheet, at the end of the script, I hide it again. The strange thing is, if I open up my Excel-file first, and then the CSV-file, it's working fine, but vica versa it doesn't.

Comment: Then you probably miss "Sheets("Hulpblad").activate?" Although activating sheets is usually not needed, but your case seems different.

Comment: I've just tried this, but unfortunately this keeps giving the same error :(

Comment: Probably it has something to do with the active sheet, because the way you paste is legit. Try writing this >>debug.print activesheet.name<< in 3-4 places of your code. Probably it changes the active sheet somehow.

Comment: I've tried this, did this before with MsgBox just before the paste command. It replies the correct sheet as active sheet. But it's really strange and frustating. For some kind of reason Excel blocks something when I first open the CSV-file :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no copy method in your statement. You are trying to paste the content directly